# Motors With Arduino's

Tags: arduino, digital, tinkercad

I have been working on getting some motors to work through H-bridges and managed to with this code.

```
// initialise motors
int enA = 3; // Motor 1
int in1 = 4;
int in2 = 2;

int enB = 5; // Motor 2
int in3 = 8;
int in4 = 7;

int enC = 11; // Motor 3
int in5 = 12;
int in6 = 13;

int enD = 6; // Motor 4
int in7 = 9;
int in8 = 10;

void setup()
{

  pinMode(enA, OUTPUT);   // set the outputs for motors
  pinMode(enB, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(enC, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(enD, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(in1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(in2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(in3, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(in4, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(in5, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(in6, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(in7, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(in8, OUTPUT);

}


void motorLoop(){
// setting the direction to turn and speed
  digitalWrite(in1, HIGH); // Motor 1
  digitalWrite(in2, LOW);


  digitalWrite(in3, HIGH); // Motor 2
  digitalWrite(in4, LOW);


  digitalWrite(in5, HIGH); // Motor 3
  digitalWrite(in6, LOW);


  digitalWrite(in7, HIGH); // Motor 4
  digitalWrite(in8, LOW);

// Set the speed for the Motors
  analogWrite(enA, 1);
  analogWrite(enB, 20);
  analogWrite(enC, 100);
  analogWrite(enD, 200);
};

void loop()
{
  motorLoop();
  delay(500);

}
```

However I am trying to turn the data into an array and have hit some issues.
I have never tried creating arrays with Digital inputs but have with Analog ones.
Here is a link to my project on (TinkerCAD) https://www.tinkercad.com/things/fFQKRTjhDrb-smashing-allis-kieran/editel?tenant=circuits?sharecode=6rKnUZsFtcOAetd_TufIuN8TfUgi8EupA1TMjlxiacM=

As you can see by this code I have tried to setup the enable inputs which show no errors but I am struggling setting up the OUTPUT and Speed that the motors rotate at.

```
    // initialise motors
// Motor 1
int in1 = 4;
int in2 = 2;

// Motor 2
int in3 = 8;
int in4 = 7;

// Motor 3
int in5 = 12;
int in6 = 13;

// Motor 4
int in7 = 9;
int in8 = 10;

// Array of PWM's
int i = 0;
byte pwms[i] = {3,5,6,11};
byte numberPwms = 4;

void setup()
{

  pinMode(in1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(in2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(in3, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(in4, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(in5, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(in6, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(in7, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(in8, OUTPUT);

  for(byte i = 0; i <= numberPwms; i++){
    pinMode(pwms[i], OUTPUT);
  };

}


void motorLoop(){
// setting the direction to turn and speed
  digitalWrite(in1, HIGH); // Motor 1
  digitalWrite(in2, LOW);


  digitalWrite(in3, HIGH); // Motor 2
  digitalWrite(in4, LOW);


  digitalWrite(in5, HIGH); // Motor 3
  digitalWrite(in6, LOW);


  digitalWrite(in7, HIGH); // Motor 4
  digitalWrite(in8, LOW);

// Set the speed for the Motors

  for(byte i = 0; i < numberPwms; i++){
    analogWrite(pwms[i], 200);
  };

};

void loop()
{
  motorLoop();
  delay(500);

}
```

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated :D

Answer (score 0):

Your for loop counts 5 times. Try changing it to this:

```cpp
for (byte i = 0; i < numberPwms; i++) {
    pinMode(pwms[i], OUTPUT);
};
```

Also your array `pwms[]` is initialized with 0 elements, but should work anyway. But you can change it.

```
uint8_t pwms[] = {3, 5, 6, 11};
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your help. I have tried editing the code with your suggestion but still get the same error.

Comment: error: array bound is not an integer constant before ']' token In function 'void setup()':

Comment: Hi does anyone have an idea why I am getting this constant error?